# How to Properly Pull NLog DB ConnectionString from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, nlog, asp.net-core-3.1

I have my `nlog.config` file setup with a database target and want to read connectionstring from `appsettings.json` (and for anyone interested, the value in `appsettings` is actually stored in Azure KeyVault). What is the proper way to do this? I have ASP.NET core 3.1 application.

`nlog.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--The first nLog section internal log file logs the NLog configuration issues, Don't remove this-->
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="debug"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\foo.txt">


  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.Logging"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
  
    <variable name="defaultLayout" value="${date} ${threadid} ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger} ${ndc} - ${message}${newline}" />
    <variable name="logDirectory" value="./logs/${shortdate}"/>
    <variable name="apiFileLogPath" value="c:\temp\api-nlog.txt"/>
    
    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <target name="dbTarget"
                xsi:type="Database"
                commandText="..."
            connectionString="${configsetting:item=NLogConfiguration.ConnectionString}">
            <!--<connectionString></connectionString>-->
        </target>
        <!-- write to the void aka just remove -->
        <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
    </targets>

    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>

        <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
        <!--<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />-->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="dbTarget" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Relevant part of `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "NLogConfiguration": {
    "ConnectionString": "..."
  }
}
```

I have a breakpoint in my code to inspect the database target but the connectionString value doesn't get set. it is staying as `${configsetting:item=NLogConfiguration.ConnectionString}`

I don't have any NLog code at startup. I have a wrapper class around NLog and am initializing it that way. That class is shown below:

`DBLogManager`

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web;
using NLog;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace DBLog.DBLogManager
{

    public class DBLogManager : IDBLogManager
    {
        static ILogger InitializeDBLogManager()
        {
            XmlDocument nLogConfig = new XmlDocument();
            var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "nlog.config");

            NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration(path);
            
            return LogManager.GetLogger("AppLogger");

        }
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = InitializeDBLogManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a XML error in your config `internalLogFile="c:\temp\foo.txt>`. Is that a copy paste bug? (missing quote)

Comment: @Julian yes copy-paste bug. Thanks. I updated it.

Comment: @Bmoe Maybe also include the code that initializes the Host, and actually loads the appsettings, since NLog needs a little help to access the appsettings from the Host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `${configsetting}` you need at least the package [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging) or one of the dependent packages like NLog.Web.AspNetCore or NLog.Extensions.Hosting.

Normally you would use `.UseNLog()` on `IHostBuilder`, see [NLog - Getting started with ASP.NET Core 3](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3)

To manual register the Microsoft Extension `IConfiguration` with `${configsetting}`:

```cs
IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(path: "AppSettings.json").Build();
NLog.Extensions.Logging.ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer.DefaultConfiguration = config;
```

See [NLog - ConfigSetting Layout Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer)

Comment: Is the `AddJsonFile` line required? I don't have that but my application is still able to read for `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I assume it's because you just re-used existing documentation which apparently folks didn't understand in the first place. I guess there was an expectation you would provide a working sample. The lines of code you posted, I personally wouldn't know where they go unless I worked with Startup code before.

Comment: You need to assign `NLog.Extensions.Logging.ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer.DefaultConfiguration`. You could also resolve the Configuration, depending of the rest of your code

Comment: @Julian where exactly we can put this code in`program.cs`?

Comment: @RahulHendawe In the `Main`?

Answer (score 3):

I would change the `DBLogManager` to this:

```cs
namespace DBLog.DBLogManager
{
    public class DBLogManager : IDBLogManager
    {
        // NLog will automatically load NLog.config from AppDomain.BaseDirectory
        private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("AppLogger");
    }
}
```

And just add `UseNLog()` like this:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseNLog();
```

If you want to have NLog Logger created before the IHostBuilder, then do this (Instead of `NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog`):

```cs
var logger = LogManager.Setup()
                       .LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()
                       .GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: Julian's answer actually helped and was before yours. I just had to put the pieces together. Thanks.

Comment: @bmoe Yes no problem. I just wanted to highlight that the code included in `DBLogManager` was unnecessary.

Comment: I guess this answer is better, so feel free to mark as answer :)